# SubSonic SimpleRepository and Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, subsonic

On a bit of a learning curve. Know one of you gurus can help me out.

I'm looking into SubSonic (SimpleRepository) and StructureMap. Really trying to get my head around them both.

I want to use SimpleRepository for the ease of use and letting my models define the database rather than pull off of or create a DB structure initially.

I create a concrete class that inherits from SimpleRepository

```
public class DataRepository : SimpleRepository
{
    public DataRepository() :   
        base("Application", SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations) 
        { }  
}
```

Add this to my Application Initialization

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(
    x => x.ForRequestedType<DataRepository>()  
        .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<DataRepository>()  
        .CacheBy(InstanceScope.Hybrid));
```

And now I'm sure that everywhere in the app i use the same SimpleRepository.

Am I making this too complex? Or am I on the right track here. I know that you don't know all the other particulars so speak to me in generalities too. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at DimeCasts.net
http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/StructureMap

Comment: Thanks Podge. I have. I take another look to learn more. I've been using the model that I outlined above and it's been working find. No real performance hits that I've been able to notice. App is going into full swing here in the next couple of weeks so I'll be able to learn more from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed one of the core ideas of DI here.  That idea being the use of interfaces to abstract the calling code from the concrete class that actually implements the functionality.

```
public interface IDataRepository { }

internal class DataRepository : SimpleRepository, IDataRepository
{
}

ObjectFactory.Initialize(
    x => x.ForRequestedType<IDataRepository>()  
        .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<DataRepository>()  
        .CacheBy(InstanceScope.Hybrid));
```

Now all the client code should resolve/reference only the IDataRepository interface.

Comment: Thanks. I do see the relationship between interfaces and DI. And like the idea of the DataRepository class being internal. 

It really doesn't change my code much. It adds the ability for it to change later since it interface. 

I guess my real question was more of how I was instantiating the SimpleRepository that is needed. Deriving my class from SimpleRepository and using the constructor to get the correct SimpleRepository and then using DI to put it all together.

Comment: Sorry for not selecting this as the answer a *long* time ago.